# Low level caching for collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I want to use Redis to do some low level caching in my Rails app.
In a controller I normally us this to get all books:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.order(:title)
  end
end
```

And the view iterates over this:

```
<ul>
  - @books.each do |book|
    <li>= "#{book.title} - #{book.author}"</li>
</ul>
```

Now I want the exact same result but then cached. I have Redis setup and running. So should I use a `cached_books` method in the controller like this:

```
@books = Book.cached_books.order(:title)
```

And leave the view as it is, or use `book.cached_title` and `book.cached_author` in the view and leave the controller as it is?

And how would a `cached_books` method look like in the `Book` model?

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def cached_books
    Rails.cache.fetch([self, "books"]) { books.to_a }
  end
end
```

For simplicity sake I leave out expire strategies for now, but obviously they need to be there.

Comment: I wouldnt add caching in models

Comment: Just checking: Did you read the [guide about caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)?

Comment: Sure, but I'm looking for specific model caching for a collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So should I use a cached_books method in the controller like this:

Yes, you can. Although there's some gotchas you have to be aware of.
`Book` is `ActiveRecord`. When you call `Book.something` (e.g. `Book.all`, or just even `Book.order(:title)` it returns you a `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which is basically wrapper for array of `Book`s (this wrapper prevents of firing unnecessary queries, boosting perfomance).

You can't save the whole result of a query in Redis. Say, you can save a JSON string of an array of hashes with model attributes, e.g.

```
[{
  id: 1,
  title: 'How to make a sandwich",
  author: 'Mr. cooker'
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'London's Bridge',
  author: 'Fergie'
}]
```

And then you can 'decrypt' this thing into the array after. Something like

```
def cached_books(key)
  # I suggest you to native wrapper
  if result = $redis.hget 'books_cache', key
    result.map do { |x| Book.new(x) }
  end
end
```

And also, you will have to serialise attributes before putting them into the cache.

Ok, now you have collections which can be iterated in the view with same data, although you can't call `order` on a cached collection, as it is a plain array (you may call `sort`, but the idea is to cache **already** sorted data).

Well... does it worth it? Actually, not really. If you need to cache this piece – probably, best way is to cache a rendered page, not a query result.

Should you use `cached_title` and `cached_author` – that's the good question. First of all, it depends on what `cached_title` may be. If it is a string – there's nothing you can cache. You get a `Book` through DB request, or you get `Book` from cache – in any way the `title` will be presented in it, as it is a simple type. But let's look closer to the `author`. Most likely it is going to be a relation to another model `Author` and this is the place where cache suits perfectly great. You can re-define `author` method inside the book (or define new and avoid nasty effects Rails may have in complex queries in the future) and see if there's a cache. If yes, return the cache. If not – query the DB, save result to the cache and return it.

```
def author
  Rails.cache.fetch("#{author_id}/info", expires_in: 12.hours) do
    # block executed if cache is not founded
    # it's better to alias original method and call it here
    #instead of directly Author.find call though
    Author.find(author_id) 
  end
end
```

Or less convenient, but more "safe":

```
def cached_author
  Rails.cache.fetch("#{author_id}/info", expires_in: 12.hours) do
    author
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation, this is very useful for me!